# websocket intermittent connection response 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, websocket

I am implementing support for websockets within my company's platform. It uses nginx, and what I'm seeing is that sometimes the websocket connection works properly and sometimes the connection fails to upgrade with a 404 response - telling me that likely the upgrade isn't getting forwarded, which was my original problem occurring all the time.

The nginx code looks like:

```
      # Deny access to .map files
      location ~* \.map$ {
        deny all;
      }

      <% if !ENV['WEBSOCKET_ROUTE'].nil? && !ENV['WEBSOCKET_ROUTE'].empty? %>
        <% cable = (!ENV['TEST_BASEPATH_VARIABLE'].nil? && !ENV['TEST_BASEPATH_VARIABLE'].empty?) ? "#{ENV['BASEPATH']}/#{ENV['WEBSOCKET_ROUTE']}" : "/#{ENV['WEBSOCKET_ROUTE']}" %>
        <% proxy_pass_field = "http://app#{cable}" %>
        location <%= cable %> {
            <% if !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].nil? && !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].empty? %>proxy_http_version <%= ENV["PROXY_HTTP_VERSION"] %>;<% end %> 
            proxy_pass <%= proxy_pass_field %>;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $http_connection;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_read_timeout <%= !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].nil? && !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].empty? ? ENV["NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS"] : 60 %>;
            proxy_request_buffering <%= (ENV['NGINX_DISABLE_PROXY_REQUEST_BUFFERING'] == 'true') ? 'off' : 'on' %>;
        }
      <% end %>

      location / {
        # root location for static assets
        root /opt/app/public;

        # for uri's not found in public assets look for index.html, if doesn't exist fall back to @app
        try_files $uri $uri/index.html @app;
      }

      location @app {
          <% if !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].nil? && !ENV['PROXY_HTTP_VERSION'].empty? %>proxy_http_version <%= ENV["PROXY_HTTP_VERSION"] %>;<% end %> 
          proxy_pass http://app;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $reqstart;
          proxy_read_timeout <%= !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].nil? && !ENV['NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS'].empty? ? ENV["NGINX_PROXY_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS"] : 60 %>;
          proxy_redirect off;
          proxy_request_buffering <%= (ENV['NGINX_DISABLE_PROXY_REQUEST_BUFFERING'] == 'true') ? 'off' : 'on' %>;
      }
```

In the above config, the only new code I have added is the part for websockets.

In the websocket location logic, the ultimate value of `cable` could either be `/basepath/websocket` or `/websocket`, depending on how applications are deployed. They might be deployed as subdomain.root.com or root.com/basepath. Right now I am testing with only the `/websocket` location where the application is deployed as subdomain.root.com.

I am baffled as to why sometimes the connection succeeds and sometimes the connection returns a 404. The application itself is written in Ruby on Rails and uses actioncable, Rails' flavor of websockets.